# Cannot 'make' program in Linux (autoreconf failure)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make

I want to compile a program called crisprtools. I am supposed to run ./autogen.sh but it says:

> Preparing the crisprtools build system...please wait
>
> Found GNU Autoconf version 2.69
>   Found GNU Automake version 1.14.1
>   Found GNU Libtool version 2.4.2
>
> Automatically preparing build ... Warning: autoreconf failed
>   Attempting to run the preparation steps individually
>
> Preparing build ... ERROR: aclocal failed

What could cause this?

---

If you need more info just ask and I will provide.

Answer (score 0):

You very likely have a different version of autoconf/automake than the one they used. Have a look around in the original src tree see if you can find it. For example:

```
$ head aclocal.m4
# generated automatically by aclocal 1.11.6 -*- Autoconf -*-
```

Then install the right version if it doesn't match your `automake --version`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install automake1.11
```

Same for autoconf:

```
$ head configure
#! /bin/sh
# Guess values for system-dependent variables and create Makefiles.
# Generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68 for parallel 20121122.
```